Link prediction using edge features/attributes in PyTorch geometric
I have a custom homogeneous graph dataset with undirected edges, where each edge has 22 features and each node has 2 features. I would like to perform link prediction on this dataset using the edge features. I attempted to do so using a PyTorch geometric example, which demonstrates link prediction based on node features.
How can I use edge features for link prediction instead of node features, as shown in the example?
A similar question has been asked before, but it didn't receive much attention.
